# I have to tables I want to join them and also want to use group by clause using lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql-server, lambda, asp.net-mvc-5

The below is the SQL query, for this i want to write lambda expression. the entity model for the Enrollment_Policy and Enrollment_MemberPolicy tables is MCEntities.

```
select mp.PolicyId, p.PolicyNo from 
Enrollment_Policy p inner join Enrollment_MemberPolicy mp 
on mp.PolicyId=p.ID
where mp.UHID=123 group by mp.PolicyId, p.policyNO
```

I got stuck at how to write group by clause. Please some one help me.

Comment: Yes I understood this it is working fine and i want to add where clause to it. There is a field called UHID, this fileld is in Enrollment_MemberPolicy table. So what i need is here is where Enrollment_MemberPolicy.UHID = 123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can achieve this. Let's say you have Foo and Bar classes:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can operate them like this:

```
var arr = new List<Foo>() {new Foo(){Id=1, Prop1 = "test"}};
var arr2 = new List<Bar>() {new Bar(){Id=1, Prop2 = "test"}};
var arr3 = arr.Join(arr2, foo => foo.BarId, bar => bar.Id, (foo, bar) => new {foo, bar})
    .Where(t=>t.foo.Prop1=="test")
    .GroupBy(t => new {t.foo.Prop1, t.bar.Prop2});
```

Comment: Can you please help me to add where clause to it. where i can add where clause?